# Backbone.js model relations: speeding up performance

Tags: javascript, performance, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have three associated models: *Segments* each have two *GeoPoints*, with associations stored as *GeoPointOnSegments*. On the server side this is straightforward Rails code, with a has_many :through relationship. On the client side, the following is the Backbone code I have written. (A note: I allow for client-side creation of data and then batch upload; that's why there is some logic to deal with both local and server ids.)

The problem I am finding is that this code is very slow when I have hundreds of models. Specifically it's the following line in geo_point.coffee:

```
masterRouter.geo_point_on_segments.select ...
```

That's doing a filter on every single GeoPointOnEntry model in order to find which ones are connected to a given GeoPoint. (Note that there can be more than one Segment connected to a GeoPoint.) Any suggestions for how to improve performance?

Ideas I have had:

- Make use of functionality provided by https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational assuming that has something to offer
- On the server-side, produce nested JSON, perhaps with some redundancy.
- Create a client-side index of sorts with a JavaScript hash.

Have any other, better ideas?

**geo_point.coffee**

```
class App.Models.GeoPoint extends Backbone.Model
  name: 'geo_point'
  getGeoPointOnSegments: ->
    masterRouter.geo_point_on_segments.select (gpos) =>
      if @isNew()
        return gpos.get('geo_point_cid') == @cid
      else 
        return gpos.get('geo_point_id') == @id
    , this
  getSegments: ->
    _.compact _.map @getGeoPointOnSegments(), (gpos) =>
      gpos.getSegment() unless gpos.get('markedForDelete')
  getConnectedGeoPoints: ->
    _.compact _.flatten _.map @getSegments(), (s) =>
      s.getGeoPoints() unless s.get('markedForDelete')
```

**geo_point_on_segment.coffee**

```
class App.Models.GeoPointOnSegment extends Backbone.Model
  name: 'geo_point_on_segment'
  getGeoPoint: ->
    if local = masterRouter.geo_points.getByCid(@get 'geo_point_cid')
      return local
    else if server = masterRouter.geo_points.get(@get 'geo_point_id')
      return server
  getSegment: ->
    if local = masterRouter.segments.getByCid(@get 'segment_cid')
      return local
    else if server = masterRouter.segments.get(@get 'segment_id')
      return server
```

**segment.coffee**

```
class App.Models.Segment extends Backbone.Model
  name: 'segment'
  getGeoPointOnSegments: ->
    _.compact masterRouter.geo_point_on_segments.select (gpos) =>
      if gpos.isNew()
        return gpos.get('segment_cid') == @cid
      else if gpos.get('markedForDelete')
        return null
      else
        return gpos.get('segment_id') == @id
    , this
  getGeoPoints: ->
    _.map @getGeoPointOnSegments(), (gpos) =>
      gpos.getGeoPoint() unless gpos.get('markedForDelete')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better not to have the relation model, `GeoPointOnSegment`, in Backbone.

The structure I would like to work is:

- each point has a collection with the segments it belongs to
- each segment has a collection/array with the points

This is easy to do if, when you instantiate your data from JSON, you do something like:

- initialize all the points
- initialize all the segments
- for each GeoPointOnSegment, add the point to the segment's collection, and the segment to the point's collection. Retrieving the point's and the segment's collection is fast, as it's by id (and indexed by Backbone).

Also, when you create new segments, you have to maintain these associations.

It is a client-side index, but integrated in the models.